# spawn EACCES- Aws lambda function getting error

Tags: aws-lambda

I am invoking aws lambda function from aws console and I am getting an error, Please help me my code is blowing

```
const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', ["-framerate", "0.5", "-i", myarray[0], "-i", 
    myarray[1], "-i", myarray[2], "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", '-codec:v', 'libx264', 
   "/var/task/bin/video.mp4"]);
```

---

> Error: spawn EACCES
>   
>      at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>   
>      at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
>   
>      at exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
>   
>      at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/var/task/handler.js:23:22)
>   
>      at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
>   
>      at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
>   
>      at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)

My Code

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;


var myarray = [];
//module.exports.hello
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

process.env.PATH = require("path").join(__dirname, "bin") + ":" + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'] +'; chmod 755 /tmp/bin/ffmpeg';

console.log(process.env.PATH);

GetImagesFromS3();

setTimeout(() => {
  const ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', ["-framerate", "0.5", "-i", myarray[0], "-i", myarray[1], "-i", myarray[2], "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", '-codec:v', 'libx264', '/temp/video.mp4']);
  ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`${data}`);
  });
  ffmpeg.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log('close', code)
  });
  ffmpeg.on('error', (code) => {
    console.log('error', code)
  });
}, 5000);
});
};


// get images from s3 bucket
function GetImagesFromS3() {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
var params = {
  Bucket: 'hhotimages'
};
s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
  var bucketContents = data.Contents;
  for (var i = 0; i < bucketContents.length; i++) {
    var urlParams = {
      Bucket: 'hhotimages',
      Key: bucketContents[i].Key
    };
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', urlParams, function (err, url) {
      console.log('the url of the image is', url);
      myarray.push(url);
    });
    }

  });
  });
 }
```

Comment: is it working ok when you test it from the console?

Comment: nothing working getting same error

Comment: can you share the complete function? or part of it which replicates the issue... get your function to run successfully through the tests in the console before invoking it from other places.

Comment: @AIqbalRaj i have added my code please help me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already shipping ffmpeg with your lambda function or else you would be getting `ENOENT`.

However, the `ffmpeg` you've packaged needs the executable bit set (`chmod +x ffmpeg` prior to packaging). Without this you do not have permission to execute ffmpeg, which is probably why you're getting `EACCES`.

You *might* also get this if your ffmpeg was compiled for something other than the lambda environment.

Comment: For a full discussion of using ffmpeg in lambda, can I recommend this detailed guide: https://intoli.com/blog/transcoding-on-aws-lambda/